Calculate the z score matrix in python
I want a pure numpy solution if possible.
I have a grayscale image. I have sampled 75 (15x5) cells in the image, calculating the average pixel value for each cell, resulting in a 15x5 matrix. Now, I want to construct a z score matrix, that uses a row-wise average and row-wise standard deviation. So, each element in the row consisting of 5 columns is a z score for that element calculated over that row.
I have tried the following code:
pixelzscore=(pixelscore-np.average(pixelscore,axis=1))/np.std(pixelscore,axis=1)

This expectedly does not work as the sizes of the operands are not equal.
Is there a pure numpy pythonic way to calculate this quickly without resorting to the scipy function? I just do not want to load additional packages that I don't actually need.

What is pixelscore here?  np.average and np.std should both return a 15-element vector.

It is a 15x5 matrix, as mentioned. You cannot subtract a vector from a matrix. Two folks provided correct answers.

Since you have the same mean/std in every cell of a row, you can calculate this factor once per row, then use np.tile to repeat over all columns, e.g.:
pixelzscore = pixelscore - np.tile(np.mean(pixelscore, axis=1)/np.std(pixelscore, axis=1), (5, 1)).T


Your code is fine, you just need to use the keepdims argument.
p = pixelscore
z = (p - p.mean(1, keepdims=True)) / p.std(1, keepdims=True)

Alternatively you can also do something like:
z = (p - p.mean(1)[:, None]) / p.std(1)[:, None]

